# bash script for check specific count is exceed or not in the log file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

firstly I want to say I'm newly to this site and need help from you guys.

I want this script to add to cron job.

requirement is -

Show "warning" when the **count exceed 250 per second** (3rd parameter in the below sample log) on **/opt/var/log/log_file**

sample log -

2, 16/05/06 10:48:46, **387**, 1000, +1258, 7, 7:9:4, , 1, 0, 4

Comment: First time? Good to check [mcve]. Anyways I have an answer for you that might help.

Comment: Yeah, not enough of a start from you.  You need to first learn how to create a script that emails you the warnings-- with no more information that what you gave, I don't think you have it yet.  Then I'd use `awk -F,` to check $3's value for the warning.  After you have a start, then post a question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script

```
#!/bin/bash #or whichever shell you use.
var=$(tail -n 1 /opt/var/log/log_file)
third_param=$(awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}{print $3}' <<< "$var")
if [ "$third_param" -gt "250" ]
then
echo "Print your customized warning here"
fi
```

does the job for you.

Save the script and check [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/) on how to add it to crontab.

**References:**

1. [GNU User Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html).
2. [Tail manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html).

Comment: If he is going to save the script and add it to crontab, he need not I guess.

Comment: Some extra code up there, you could use
`awk -F, 'END{print $3}' $file`

However, in real world situations, I'm not sure that the log file will have only one new entry per run of this script.  If it does, it seems odd the warning is part of the logging mechanism itself.  The OP didn't give enough information.